# Change the site name programmatically for a specific page

Tags: theming

I am trying to change the site name when a user enters specific pages on my website. 
I know the variable for the site name is `$site_name` and is being retrieved from the system.tpl.html file.

So I am trying to set different site names depending the URL; for example, when a user visits /about_us, the site name should change.

In my template.php file, I have captured the path in a variable.

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias();
if ($path == 'about_us') {
  $site_name = 'New title';
}
```

This won't work.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you mean page.tpl.php (not system.tpl.html, which isn't a standard Drupal file).

That said, you need to put your code in a `hook_preprocess_page()` function inside template.php, and actually alter the template variables that are passed in. At the moment you're just creating a variable called `$site_name` in the local scope, and Drupal has no way to pick that up.

Try this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias();
  if ($path == 'about_us') {
    $vars['site_name'] = 'New title';
  }
}
```

Have a look at [Setting up variables for use in a template](http://drupal.org/node/223430) for a bit more info.

Comment: yes:) thank you for your quick answer. It worked. Millions of thanks:):)

Comment: @Nicole No probs, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 4):

The site name is set in [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) using the following code.

```
  $variables['site_name'] = (theme_get_setting('toggle_name') ? filter_xss_admin(variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')) : '');
```

In your theme, or module, you should use code similar to the following one. (Replace `mycode` with the short name of your module/theme.)

```
function mycode_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (theme_get_setting('toggle_name') && drupal_get_path_alias() == 'about_us') {
    $variables['site_name'] = filter_xss_admin('The new site name');
  }
}
```

The call to [filter_xss_admin()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/filter_xss_admin/7) is not necessary, if you are not using the input obtained from a user.
You should always check the value returned by `theme_get_setting('toggle_name')`, as the site name could be toggled off for the theme currently used.